# Kotlin coroutines industry practices

Tags: kotlin, asynchronous, kotlin-coroutines

I have written this function to load data from db, change it asynchronously and return the new data. It appears to work fine, but since I am new to koltin, I wanted to ask if this code is ok by industry standards.

```
    override fun update(resourceCommand: UpdateResourceCommand): List<Resource> = runBlocking {
        val resources = resourceCommand.resources.map {
            async {
                val resource = load(it)
                resource.isProtected = it.isProtected
                resource
            }
        }.awaitAll()
        return@runBlocking resources
    }
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: I think you should rather post this on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/. StackOverflow is more for programming problems, not for refactoring/review.

Comment: Is `load()` function suspend or not? If not then I believe this code doesn't really work, it loads resources sequentially. You have to use `runBlocking(Dispatchers.IO) { ... }` instead. But generally, this is not a typical or good example of using coroutines. `runBlocking` should be generally avoided.

Comment: I don't think `load` is suspended. It uses JDBC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is kind of subjective, but my take on it is that is not really idiomatic to create a variable to only return it after. I believe your code can be made more compact like

```
override fun update(resourceCommand: UpdateResourceCommand): List<Resource> = runBlocking {
    resourceCommand.resources.map {
        async {
            load(it).apply {
                isProtected = it.isProtected
            }
        }
    }.awaitAll()
}
```

Whether it's better or more to industry standards I don't know and is subjective. But that's how I would do it.

Comment: I fully agree that your code is more idiomatic that the original. All I would add is that it is also idiomatic to make `update` a suspend function instead of calling `runBlocking` - but then that forces the functions that call `update` to also be `suspend`, and in turn their callers, etc. causing a proliferation of `suspend`. If the application as a whole is not based around coroutines, then I think calling `runBlocking` here is ok.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! One person here said that this function may not load resources concurrently and after some tests I suspect it to be true (when I print the current time inside async there is a 20-50 millisecond difference between each run). Does your version fix that?

Comment: @Newbee No, it doesn't fix it, as this version is totally equivalent to your version. It does exactly the same thing but with nicer syntax. See broot's comment for how to fix it to make it concurrent.